# difference between chmod 777 and chmod 007

Tags: linux, security, permissions, chmod

What is the difference between chmod 777 and chmod 007? if 'others' means everyone, doesn't that strongly suggest the truth that chmod 777 = chmod 007?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It may suggest that, but it isn't the case.

The first digit is "owner" permissions, the second is "group" permissions - and the owner and group are viewable with `ls -l`, and the third is "others", which literally means those that aren't either the owner or in the group.

So `007` means that neither the owner or group members can read, write, or execute the file, while everyone else can do all three.

Comment: can you provide a real life example where this scenario exists (007)? Thanks

Comment: @adhg No :)  I cannot think of a specific scenario that would need this, that couldn't be acheived through better means.

Answer (score 5):

No. `0007` explicitly *denies* access by the owner and group, regardless of the other permissions.

Comment: I think you meant `007`

Comment: @Jay: They're exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

If 'others' means everyone, then yes. However it does not mean that.

Very briefly it is: User, group, people_not_previous_group